# How to remove fade-out transition in tooltip component from element-ui?

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

I want remove the tooltip immediately after loosing focus, but it disapper only with default transition time.

I use tooltip component from element-ui https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/tooltip

```js
<el-tooltip 
    placement="bottom"
    :content="my text"
    :enterable="false"
>
  <div class="custom-item">Next</div>
</el-tooltip>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use transition prop with empty value.

```html
<el-tooltip
  placement="bottom"
  :content="my text"
  :enterable="false"
  transition="" <-- add this prop
>
  <div class="custom-item">Next</div>
</el-tooltip>
```

Comment: Still same transition. transition="" doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to achieve the same but unfortunately, they have 200ms debounce hardcoded on mouseleave

`this.debounceClose = debounce(200, () => this.handleClosePopper());`

https://github.com/ElemeFE/element/blob/dev/packages/tooltip/src/main.js#L75

---

Hacky way to achieve it:

```
<el-tooltip
  transition=""
  :disabled="tooltipDisabled"
>
  <button
    @mouseleave="tooltipDisabled = true"
    @mouseenter="tooltipDisabled = false"
  ></button>
</el-tooltip>
```